# Clicking image from camera, and cropping it, mode automatically converting into landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

I am taking image through camera, and after that cropping the image, when I add this image into list view, image automatically converted into landscape mode. I need to show it in portrait mode. 
one more question, I want to show the cropped image into 100 *100 image view, I think I need to reduce resolution of image so it can be visible fully into image view of size 100*100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, when i open this image for cropping it shows in portrait mode, and saves in that only.